# Error: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'source'" OR "KeyError: 'source'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

**Aim:** To plot the feature importance

**Error 1:** AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'source'

**Error 2:** KeyError: 'source'

**Where?:** names = [data.source[i] for i in indices] **OR** names = [data['source'] == i for i in indices]

I am not an expert in python and pandas, could you please help me correct this chunk of code? And also if an advice over syntax to avoid similar errors in future?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data_with_anomalies.csv')
source = pd.DataFrame(data)
target = data['Anomaly']
source = source.drop(columns = ['Anomaly_Tag'])

model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(source, target)
print(model.feature_importances_)

importances = model.feature_importances_

# Below chunk is referred from another question on stackoverflow
# Sort feature importances in descending order
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
```

**Getting error 1 with below line:**

```
# Rearrange feature names so they match the sorted feature importances
names = [data.source[i] for i in indices]
```

**OR if I change it to below, I get error 2:**

```
names = [data['source'] == i for i in indices]

plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature Importance")
plt.bar(range(source.shape[1]), importances[indices])
plt.xticks(range(source.shape[1]), names, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In both cases you are essentially attempting to access a column of the data frame named 'source', which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`names = data.reindex(indices)`